# Beautifulsoup webscraping - extract values from within <a> tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I am using bs4 to scrape indeed.com for jobs (link [here](https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=devops&start=0)). I have been able to successfully extract the title, company and summary without any issues.

Now I want to take this a step further and extract the sublink provided when the user clicks on each of the job titles, e.g. this [link](https://uk.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=e5b27ae62cb7c45f&q=devops&tk=1fk3dkeg7r7pq801&from=web&advn=9287270971456301&adid=373208110&ad=-6NYlbfkN0C4nje_eUcJygKnWiKpJdNC2fyftdmI8CPysYuvSAU4r20MHZIHrvC6KXdRUaJAD4WX3mY-9rMaN57MmM-6NmgCaxxfPYUE37UnxzEsvYC5PH8MQ74KC631nMIsli7j82AoWx1DO6i_hoEyed7XZoZJd8a9HG-8_JTw-_zpHjHuPWkYpU6L1L4jmBBLUh4Z8eUlzib-O4NZSfiGRREGFpYZJx9QMMB6Yc09rA12dVihiMlqjP3xaNDctkbMHuq97ysMjbp_msDPOJGZMahb8ixVTNEOQmsbbtBD-So9KOuZRsd3209X5Iwu2xQMLG7IrUiHxCOMqsW4BGlEjn5X5S-msJrHXXGWaEXAJcMUYPsSGjKagMBAh8Hw9t1nK-8s_OLVo8yYu6au1A%3D%3D&pub=4a1b367933fd867b19b072952f68dceb&vjs=3), so I can extract additional information such as specific technologies required for each role.

I noticed that the sublink url contains `jk=e5b27ae62cb7c45f`, which is the job key contained in the html that I can use to create the sublink. Unfortunately, I am struggling to extract this job key!

I have identified the job key is nested in an `<a>` tag, labeled `data-jk`:

[image]

Here is my function so far using bs4:

```
def transform(soup):
    divs = soup.find_all('a', class_= 'tapItem')
    
    for item in divs:
        title = item.find('h2', {'class':'jobTitle-color-purple'}).text
        id = item.find('a')
        
        print(title)
        print(id)
        
transform(soup)
```

Which returns the following results:

```
newDevOps Engineer
<a class="turnstileLink companyOverviewLink" data-tn-element="companyName" href="/cmp/Tata-Consultancy-Services-(tcs)" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Tata Consultancy Services (TCS)</a>
newDevOps Engineer - Sydney, Australia
None
DevOps Engineers
<a class="turnstileLink companyOverviewLink" data-tn-element="companyName" href="/cmp/CGI" rel="noopener" target="_blank">CGI</a>
Graduate Software Developer/Programmer (DevOps)
<a class="turnstileLink companyOverviewLink" data-tn-element="companyName" href="/cmp/Tata-Consultancy-Services-(tcs)" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Tata Consultancy Services (TCS)</a>
Cloud Engineer (Entry level, AWS training provided)
```

As you can see, I am able to extract `title` successfully but not `id`, since I do not know how to select the `data-jk` value from within the `<a>` tag. I am also confused as to why the `<a>` tag with `class: 'tapItem'` does not even appear when I call `item.find('a')`?

I've scoured stackoverflow but am unable to find a similar question to mine. Hoping someone here can help me figure this out!

Comment: `title` doesn't have directly `href` but all offer is inside `<a>` which I can even see on your image - at the top of black background.

Comment: You have to start few tags above `'job_seen_beacon` - in `id="mosaic-provider-jobcards"` - to get this `<a>`

Comment: thanks for your suggestions! i've updated my question to give a bit more context. i've realised I needed to start a few tags above so am using class: 'tapItem' but still running into issues extracting data-jk

Comment: `data-jk` is a attribute like `href` or `class`- `id["data-jk"]`, `id["href"]`, `id["class"]`

Comment: BTW: attributes are a dictionary so you can also use `id.get("data-jk"), id.get("href")` like in normal dictionary. You can even use default value `id.get("data-jk", default_value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` doesn't have directly `href` but all offer is inside `<a>` which I can even see on your image - at the top of black background (with `target="_blank"`)

You get `job_seen_beacon` which is also inside this `<a>` so you can't access this `<a>`. If you start few tags above then you can get `<a>` and href`

```
#divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'job_seen_beacon')

divs = soup.find('div', {'id': 'mosaic-provider-jobcards'}).find_all('a', {'class': 'result'})

for item in divs:

    link = item['href']
```

---

Full working example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#extract
def extract(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup
    
#transform
def transform(soup):
    #divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'job_seen_beacon')
    divs = soup.find('div', {'id': 'mosaic-provider-jobcards'}).find_all('a', {'class': 'result'})

    joblist = []
   
    for item in divs:
        title = item.find('h2', {'class':'jobTitle-color-purple'}).text
        company = item.find('span', {'class': 'companyName'}).text
        summary = item.find('div', {'class': 'job-snippet'}).text.replace('\n','')

        link = item['href']
        print(link)

        job = {
            'title': title,
            'company': company,
            'summary': summary,
            'link': link,
        }
        joblist.append(job)
        #print(job)
        print('---')
        
    return joblist

soup = extract('https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=devops&start=0')
joblist = transform(soup)

#print(joblist)
```